# How to set timer in View class?

Tags: android, multithreading, timer, draw

I am trying to set a text which acts as a timer. I'll create timer easily if i extend Activity class. But i am facing lot of problem in this View class. Here i made a code where radius of circle will be reducing and it will be increased for each touch on screen. Simultaneously i need a timer running on the top. Because i need to increase the reducing speed after every 10 seconds.

So here timer plays an important role. I tried using thread , which should update the text for every 1 second . But it is showing this exception `IllegalThreadStateException`.

Is there any other way to implement timer in this screen ? 
Or What mistake i did in my code..

Thanks for you help friends..

```
package com.kbt.testcircle;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Path;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;

public class MyView extends View {
    int radius = 100,i=0;

    boolean freeTouched = false;
    Path freePath;
    Handler handler = new Handler();

    public MyView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public MyView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public MyView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    public void calThread() {

        /*
         * Thread th=new Thread(){ public void run(){ try { sleep(2000); } catch
         * (InterruptedException e) { // TODO Auto-generated catch block
         * e.printStackTrace(); } finally{ radius-=1;
         * Log.i("kbt","inside thread 800 seconds"); } } }; th.start();
         */
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                radius -= 1;
                Log.i("kbt", "inside thread 800 seconds");
                invalidate();
            }
        }, 500);


        Log.i("kbt", "Inside thread");
    }
Thread th=new Thread()
{
    public void run(){

        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                i++;
            }
        },1000);
    }
};
    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) throws IllegalThreadStateException 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        th.start();
        Log.i("kbt","starting");
        super.onDraw(canvas);// th.start();

        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(3);
        canvas.drawCircle(getWidth() / 2, getHeight() / 2, radius, paint);
        paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(0);
        paint.setTextSize(25);
        canvas.drawText("Timer : "+i, getWidth()/4, getHeight()/4, paint);
        calThread();

        Log.i("kbt", "Inside clled");

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

        switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

            radius+=5;
            invalidate();
            /* freeTouched = true;
            freePath = new Path();
            freePath.moveTo(event.getX(), event.getY()); */
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            /* freePath.lineTo(event.getX(), event.getY());
            invalidate(); */
            break;
        }

        return true;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But it is showing this exception `IllegalThreadStateException`.

It caused by non-runnable or non-threading class. A class that extends `View` has no background thread on it, so that you get `IllegalThreadStateException`.

> Is there any other way to implement timer in this screen?

Java provided a `Timer` class to be used for all of class types:

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
TimerTask task = new TimerTask(){
    @Override
    public void run() {
    // do your thing here
    }
};
timer.schedule(task,
1, // delay the task 1ms before executed
10000); // repeating your task every 10000ms, i.e. 10 seconds
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really one to use a thread, you could only start the thread *once*. If you want to start thread for many times, use `Runnable` instead.